# Can OSSEC detect buffer overflow attacks?

Tags: ids, audit, buffer-overflow, software, hids

I am trying to detect buffer overflow by using OSSEC (a HIDS software) as mentioned in [OSSEC rules example](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/blob/master/etc/rules/attack_rules.xml#L32) and [OSSEC book](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=h37q2q3wvcUC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=ossec%20buffer%20overflow%20detection&source=bl&ots=Ua_nRUZqC_&sig=20c3o7T6YLTO5jXTH_hmnNrgiPI&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ossec%20buffer%20overflow%20detection&f=false).

How can I configure OSSEC for detect a simple buffer overflow example as the following:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    printf("Done!\n");
}
```

Comment: I think default settings include alerting on bofs and program crashes

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that OSSEC is a log-based HIDS. Knowing that, it is clear that OSSEC will be able to react only if someone (eg.: a daemon) adds a log that matches some [Buffer Overflow rule](https://depot.gril.usherbrooke.ca/fram1801/iASTD-public/blob/7a2998c5ee97b13e6a78144f1649d6a59acf9f47/OSSEC-Sysmon/rules/attack_rules.xml).

See the official code example that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for detection of stage-one attacks (shellcode in a process) there is EMET, [WDEG aka EMET II](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2017/08/09/moving-beyond-emet-ii-windows-defender-exploit-guard/) (for Windows) and Lotan (cross-platform).

Leviathan Security has posted on Lotan at least twice here:

- http://www.leviathansecurity.com/blog/reverse-engineering-firefox-and-tor-targeted-payload
- http://www.leviathansecurity.com/blog/bulk-aslr-data-analysis

EMET has been capable of similar through the [3.0 Notifier](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/14530/140) or the [5.5 Event-Log](https://adsecurity.org/?p=2579) mechanisms.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLgycMCPo4c